# Find a CFG for $\{a^ib^jc^k \mid i,j,k\ge0 , \text{if } j=1 \text{ then } i=k\}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I've tried but I can't figure out any solution. Is there any hint for me to solve the question?

Comment: There are three pieces. One for $j=0$. One for $j=1$. One for $j\ge2$. Find the CFG for each piece.  Then you get $S\to S_1\mid S_2\mid S_3$.

Comment: Please read [_how to ask a good homework question_](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284). Besides an explicit question, it is expected of you to show your partial progress, thoughts and/or where you got stuck. It will help draw more better answers faster. Otherwise, this post might be closed or downvoted.

Comment: My apologies, I am new here and haven't read the rules. I have solved the questions and uploaded my answer.

Comment: @MartinChou Please undo your edits and post an answer to your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

$ S =>S_1 \mid S_2 \mid S_3 $

$ S_1 =>AC  $

$ S_2 => aS_2c  \mid b $

$ S_3 => AbbBC $

$ A =>aA \mid epsilon  $

$ B =>bB \mid epsilon  $

$ C =>cC \mid epsilon  $